# How do I get command name of the last executed command?

Tags: shell, command-line, command-history, history-expansion

Example: I type `man ls`, than I want to get `man` only.

By using `!!` I can get `man ls` but how do I get `man`?

Comment: Hi, you can try to use fc command , `fc -rl | awk '{ print $2 }' | head -1`

Comment: `!:0` will give you word 0 (the command word itself) of the previous command.

Comment: And if you want to see the command produced by history expansion before hitting `Enter` you can use the `shell-expand-line` key sequence `M-C-e`, that is `Meta-Ctrl-e`; `Meta` is usually `Alt`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can select particular word from last typed command with `!!:` and a word designator. As a word designator you need `0`. You may find `^` and `$` useful too. From [`man bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Designators.html#Word-Designators):

> **Word Designators**
>
> **0** (zero)
>                 The zeroth word.  For the shell, this is the command word.
>
> **^**      The first argument.  That is, word 1.
>
> **$**      The last argument.

So in your case try:

```
echo !!:0
```

Comment: Second comment under my question mentions: `!:0`, what is the difference between `!:0` and `!!:0`?

Comment: You can use `!:0`, and note in `bash`, if `extglob` is enabled, it must not follow by blank, newline, `\r`, = or (.

Comment: @REACHUS `!` starts history substitution and `!!` refer to previous command. Probably single `!` in some cases denotes `!!` and indeed `echo !:0` works but `echo !` doesn't while `!!` works in both cases.

Comment: You don't need to `echo`. You can use the `p` modifier instead: `!!:0:p`

Answer (score 5):

In interactive mode, the easiest way to do this is just a keystroke combination <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>. The shortcut <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> means "recall n-th word from the previous line" (by default the last one) and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> gives it an argument 0.

This should work for interactive bash on most systems (more generally, all shells that use `readline` as its input library).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009412/bash-how-to-use-arguments-from-previous-command