# recall last command without arguments

Tags: bash

In bash, what is the shortcut to recall the last command **without** any arguments?

That seems to be the one shortcut that is missing form the various guides I have found, such as https://linuxconfig.org/linux-command-line-bash-shell-shortcuts

I would like the last used command to appear on the command line with the cursor at the end of the line so I can type the new argument I wish to supply.

Furthermore, I would like to achieve this with a single shortcut key combination along the lines of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

`!:0` does not work because it actually executes the command without giving me an opportunity to enter new argument(s).

<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> fails to produce any results in bash for me. However, the following indicates it should work, assuming `\e` refers to <kbd>Alt</kbd>

```
bind -P | grep shell-expand-line
shell-expand-line can be found on "\e\C-e".
```

I'm running Arch.

Comment: @muru that question is slightly different and the accepted answer doesn't do what I am trying to achieve. I clarified my question to make that more clear.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179854/how-do-i-get-command-name-of-the-last-executed-command#comment299158_179854

Comment: @muru you linked to a comment that suggests using Meta-Ctrl-e; (Meta is usually Alt). I tried that (trying both Alt keys) and the command does not do anything in bash for me. I'm running Arch Linux (current).

Comment: @muru I see how it works now.  !!:0 then Ctrl-Alt-E does work, but that is a lot of typing, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Just `!!:0` will get replaced with the command when it is executed. I don't even bother to expand it when using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `bash` or `zsh` in `emacs` mode, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd>. That is hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and press 0 and underscore in sequence (which on a qwerty keyboard are next to each other, though you need <kbd>Shift</kbd> for underscore).

It expands to the first syntactic word of the previous command line. That may not be the last command. For instance, if the last command line was:

```
$(echo echo foo) bar
```

It would expand to `$(echo echo foo)`, not `echo`.

If you want it to be a single key, you can use `bind` in `bash` or `bindkey` in `zsh` to bind that sequence to a key.

For instance, to bind to <kbd>F12</kbd>:

- `bash`:

  ```
  bind "\"$(tput kf12)"'": "\e0\e_"'
  ```
- `zsh`:

  ```
  bindkey -s $terminfo[kf12] '\e0\e_'
  ```

Comment: ... which is similar to the other answer of the linked post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/179861/70524 (but `_` instead of `.`)

Comment: @muru, ah yes. I didn't see the comment or linked answer. Then it's a dup or am I missing something.

Comment: so far I have been unable to get bind to work. Can you give an example of how to bind `CTRL-0` to this function?

Comment: @MountainX, see edit.

Comment: @MountainX doesn't look like `Ctrl-0` will work: https://superuser.com/a/27318/334516

Comment: @MontainX, there's no such thing as a `^0` character. `xterm` sends a 0 character when you press Ctrl+0, gnome-terminal sends nothing. For Ctrl+0 to work, you'd need to configure your terminal emulator to send a character or sequence of characters upon pressing that, which you'd then _bind_ in the shell.